# Cell dependent appearance of cell in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, tableview, model-binding

How can I change the appearance of a cell based on the status of another cell in the same column of a tableView in JavaFX.

```
colHidden.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
        return param.getValue().hiddenProperty();
    });

colHidden.setCellFactory(tc -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
    colLabel.setCellFactory(...);
```

I have a cell which contains `CheckBoxTableCell<>()`. When I select this checkbox the content of the cell `colLabel` should be replaced by asterisks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. The basic idea here is to "remember" the property corresponding to the check box in the same row, assuming the cell is not empty, and add a listener to it that updates the text. Then remove the listener from the previous property whenever the cell updates.

```
colLabel.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<RowType, ColumnType>() {
    private ObservableValue<Boolean> hiddenProperty ;

    ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (obs, wasHidden, isNowHidden) -> updateText(isNowHidden);

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(ColumnType item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (hiddenProperty != null) {
            hiddenProperty.removeListener(listener);
        }
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            hiddenProperty = null ;
        } else {
            hiddenProperty = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).hiddenProperty();
            hiddenProperty.addListener(listener);
            updateText(hiddenProperty.get());
        }
    }

    private void updateText(boolean hidden) {
        if (hidden) {
            setText("********");
        } else {
            setText(getItem().toString()); // or other format for string, etc
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `RowType` and `ColumnType` with the actual types used by `colLabel` (i.e. this assumes you have `TableColumn<RowType, ColumnType> colLabel ;`).

Comment: Thank you for this neat solution. It worked out of the box. I do not get why I have to check if the hiddenProperty != null.

Comment: @Caduceus It will be null the first time `updateItem(..)` is called (at a minimum). (Actually, it should probably be set back to null if the cell is empty, too. I'll fix that.)